# Method not allowed (Get)

Tags: java, spring

Нужна ваша помощь. Имею работающий код, но к сожалению некорректно. У меня работают все операции, кроме Get. Я пытаюсь вытянуть отдельный элемент по id и в postman получаю ошибку: `method not allowed`. В чем моя ошибка? Спасибо

```
package com.example_car_projects.Java_Cars_Project.controllers;

import com.example_car_projects.Java_Cars_Project.entity.Car;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@RestController
public class Car_Controller {

private List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();

{
    cars.add(new Car(1,"Bugatti", 1050000));
    cars.add(new Car(2,"Pagani", 4200000));
    cars.add(new Car(3,"Lamborghini",350000));
}

@GetMapping(value = "/car")
public List<Car> getCars() {
    return cars;
}

@PostMapping(value = "/car")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public Car insertCar(@RequestBody Car car) {
    cars.add(car);
    return car;
}

@PutMapping(value = "/car/{id}")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
public Car updateCar(@PathVariable int id, @RequestBody Car car) {
    final Optional<Car> first = cars.stream().filter(m -> m.getId() == id).findFirst();
    final Car carInList = first.orElseThrow(() -> new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "No movie Found"));
    final int index = cars.indexOf(carInList);
    car.setId(id);
    cars.set(index, car);
    return car;
}

@DeleteMapping(value = "/car/{id}")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
public void deleteCar(@PathVariable int id) {
    final boolean isRemoved = cars.removeIf(movie -> movie.getId() == id);
    if (isRemoved) {
        System.out.println("Movie Removed");
    } else {
        System.out.println("No such movie");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Укажи пример запроса из Postman.

Answer (score 0):

- скорее надо назвать его `/cars`, потому что выдается весь список
- если это `/car`, то лучше сделать `/car/{id}` и выдавать по айди
- выдавать весь список ресурсозатратно, а вдруг будет миллион машин в
  базе
- наличие такого запроса подразумевает наличие сервиса, который бы
  выдавал `id`

```
@GetMapping(value = "/car/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity getCarById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return CarsService.getCarById(id);
    }
```

В вашем случае, сервисом может выступать простой `forEach` по листу.